# Issues with "'x' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, error-handling, declare

I was trying to write up a simple code to try and solve matrices and came across an error. Obviously, I am just doing something stupid, so I was hoping you could come to the rescue! Whenever I run the code and input the values, it returns 'x' was not declared in this scope. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

// Row 1
cout << "Please input the first row, first column (R1:C1)" << endl;
int R1C1;
cin >> R1C1;
cout << "Please input the first row, second column (R1:C2)" << endl;
int R1C2;
cin >> R1C2;
cout << "Please input the first row, third column (R1:C3)" << endl;
int R1C3;
cin >> R1C3;
cout << "Please input the first row, fourth column (R1:C4)" << endl;
int R1C4;
cin >> R1C4;

// Row 2
cout << "Please input the second row, first column (R2:C1)" << endl;
int R2C1;
cin >> R2C1;
cout << "Please input the second row, second column (R2:C2)" << endl;
int R2C2;
cin >> R2C2;
cout << "Please input the second row, third column (R2:C3)" << endl;
int R2C3;
cin >> R2C3;
cout << "Please input the second row, fourth column (R2:C4)" << endl;
int R2C4;
cin >> R2C4;

// Row 3
cout << "Please input the third row, first column (R3:C1)" << endl;
int R3C1;
cin >> R3C1;
cout << "Please input the third row, second column (R3:C2)" << endl;
int R3C2;
cin >> R3C2;
cout << "Please input the third row, third column (R3:C3)" << endl;
int R3C3;
cin >> R3C3;
cout << "Please input the third row, fourth column (R2:C4)" << endl;
int R3C4;
cin >> R3C4;

if (R1C1 > 1)
int x = R1C1 * (1/R1C1);
cout << x; 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here

```
if (R1C1 > 1)
int x = R1C1 * (1/R1C1);
cout << x;
```

Basically means this:

```
if (R1C1 > 1){
    int x = R1C1 * (1/R1C1);
}
cout << x;
```

As you can see, the `x` isn't in the scope anymore when you print it. Its scope is limited to the body of the `if` expression. To make it less confusing, people would usually indent the `int x...` line so it is clear that it belongs to the `if` statement and isn't in the same scope as the `cout` line.

Maybe you wanted to do this instead:

```
if (R1C1 > 1){
    int x = R1C1 * (1/R1C1);
    cout << x;
}
```